# Inside Table layout table rows contents is not displaying horizontally in android using recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-tablelayout

Hi in the below I am displaying operator list displaying using recyclerview.

For this created Table layout contains table row .each row contains data that is coming from server and display via table format.

Response from server:

```
[{"email":"awdw@dv.vdv","id":"20","mobileNumber":"undefined","username":"akash4345678"}]
```

But data is displaying in vertial format want to display horizontally.

Expected output:

```
username      email        MobileNumber
akash4345678  awdw@dv.vdv  undefined
```

output for below code:

```
Username     Email    MobileNumber
akash4345678  
awdw@dv.vdv  
undefined
```

Manage_operatorlist.java:

```
private void doTheAutoRefresh() {
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Write code for your refresh logic

                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog (getActivity ());
                progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
                progressDialog.setMessage("Communicating...");
                progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
                progressDialog.show();
                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                        .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .build();

                Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl(API.URL_BASE)
                        .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                        .client (client)
                        .build();
                API service = retrofit.create (API.class);
                Call<List<GetOperatorList>> userCall = service.getopetaorlist ();
                userCall.enqueue(new Callback<List<GetOperatorList>> () {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call <List<GetOperatorList>> call, Response <List<GetOperatorList>> response) {


                        if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                            progressDialog.dismiss ( );
                            Log.d ("Response body", new Gson ( ).toJson (response.body ( )));
                            String Status = new Gson ( ).toJson (response.body ( ));
                            JSONArray jsonArray = null;

                            try {
                                JSONObject jsonObject=null;
                                jsonArray = new JSONArray (Status);
                                arrayList = new ArrayList <> ( );
                                String id;
                                // String name[]={} ;

                                for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length ();i++) {
                                    username=jsonArray.getJSONObject (i).getString ("username");
                                    email=jsonArray.getJSONObject (i).getString ("email");
                                    mobileNumber=jsonArray.getJSONObject (i).getString ("mobileNumber");

                                    //email=jsonArray.getJSONObject (i).getString ("email");
                                    //mobile_number=jsonArray.getJSONObject (i).getString ("MobileNumber");
                                    Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity ().getAssets (), "fonts/astype - Secca Light.otf");


                                    arrayList.add (username);
                                   arrayList.add (email);
                                   arrayList.add (mobileNumber);
                                   // arrayList.add (email);
                                   // arrayList.add (mobile_number);

                                }

                                // Creating Adapter object
                                SwipeRecyclerViewAdapter mAdapter = new SwipeRecyclerViewAdapter((Context) getActivity (), arrayList);


                                // Setting Mode to Single to reveal bottom View for one item in List
                                // Setting Mode to Mutliple to reveal bottom Views for multile items in List
                                ((SwipeRecyclerViewAdapter) mAdapter).setMode(Attributes.Mode.Single);

                                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);



                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace ( );

                            }

                        }

                        else  {
                            progressDialog.dismiss ();
                            Log.d("Response errorBody", String.valueOf(response.errorBody()));
                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<List<GetOperatorList>> call, Throwable t) {
                        // lv.setAdapter (adapter);
                        System.out.println("onFailure");
                        System.out.println(t.fillInStackTrace());
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity (), "Some error occurred -> ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();;
                        // progressDialog.dismiss();



                    }

                });
            }


        }, 5000);
        return ;
    }
```

ManageOperatorlist.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/realmsbg">

        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/layout_border">

        <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/manage_operator"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:background="@drawable/layout_border"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Manage Operator List"/>



        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                        <TableLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:paddingRight="10dp"
                            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">
                                <TableRow android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

                                        <TextView
                                            android:id="@+id/txtRank"
                                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                            android:layout_gravity="top"
                                            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                                            android:text="UserName"
                                            android:background="@drawable/cellborder"
                                            android:textColor="@color/color_white"
                                            android:textSize="18sp" />

                                        <TextView
                                            android:id="@+id/txtMovieName"
                                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                            android:padding="3dp"
                                            android:layout_gravity="top"
                                            android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
                                            android:text="Email"
                                            android:textColor="@color/color_white"
                                            android:background="@drawable/cellborder"
                                            android:textSize="18sp" />

                                        <TextView
                                            android:id="@+id/txtYear"
                                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                            android:layout_gravity="top"
                                            android:text="MobileNumber"
                                            android:textColor="@color/color_white"
                                            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                                            android:background="@drawable/cellborder"
                                            android:textSize="18sp" />

                                </TableRow>
                        </TableLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/empty_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="No Records"
        android:visibility="gone" />


        </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

SwipeAdapter.java:

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final SimpleViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {

        int rowPos  = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition ();


            final String item = String.valueOf (operatorlist.get (position));

            String[] strArray = new String[]{item};
            System.out.println (strArray);
           viewHolder.tvEmail.setText (strArray[0]);
//           viewHolder.tvName.setText (strArray[1]);
//           String[] strArray1=new String[]{String.valueOf (strArray)};;
//            for (int i=0;i<strArray.length;i++){
//                strArray1=strArray;
//
//
//               // viewHolder.tvEmail.setText (strArray1[1].get());
//
//            }
          //  System.out.println (strArray[1]); //prints "name"

           // viewHolder.tvName.setText ((strArray[3]));
      //  viewHolder.tvEmail.setText (strArray[0]);
           // viewHolder.txtRank.setText (strArray[1]);


            viewHolder.swipeLayout.setShowMode (SwipeLayout.ShowMode.PullOut);

            // Drag From Left
            viewHolder.swipeLayout.addDrag (SwipeLayout.DragEdge.Left, viewHolder.swipeLayout.findViewById (R.id.bottom_wrapper1));

            // Drag From Right
            viewHolder.swipeLayout.addDrag (SwipeLayout.DragEdge.Right, viewHolder.swipeLayout.findViewById (R.id.bottom_wrapper));


            // Handling different events when swiping
            viewHolder.swipeLayout.addSwipeListener (new SwipeLayout.SwipeListener ( ) {
                @Override
                public void onClose(SwipeLayout layout) {
                    //when the SurfaceView totally cover the BottomView.
                }

                @Override
                public void onUpdate(SwipeLayout layout, int leftOffset, int topOffset) {
                    //you are swiping.
                }

                @Override
                public void onStartOpen(SwipeLayout layout) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onOpen(SwipeLayout layout) {
                    //when the BottomView totally show.
                }

                @Override
                public void onStartClose(SwipeLayout layout) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onHandRelease(SwipeLayout layout, float xvel, float yvel) {
                    //when user's hand released.
                }
            });
```

Comment: The retrieved data is apparently going into the `List` for that `RecyclerView.Adapter`. How does your `TableLayout` figure into that? It seems to be in the same layout as the `RecyclerView`, and the only thing you're setting in that `onBindViewHolder()` is a single `TextView`. Shouldn't you be setting three `TextView`s per item?

Answer (score 1):

please share your SwipeRecyclerViewAdapter and xml .

or you have to update your RecyclerView xml file

Comment: Hi Falansh, This is a comment It would be better if you move the answer to comment section.

Answer (score 0):

In your xml file, `TableRow` needs to include `android:orientation="horizontal"`, because the default behavior is to layout the text views in vertical.

Apart from that, your `TableLayout` should have `android:orientation="vertical"`, because otherwise all your rows will appear on a single line.

Comment: Please give more details. Is the result the same? Do you see an error?

Comment: No same content was displaying in vertical format .want to show in horizontial format